# Added new node to eks, new pods still being scheduled on old nodes

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, scheduler, amazon-eks, kubernetes-deployment

I have a terraform-managed EKS cluster. It used to have 2 nodes on it. I doubled the number of nodes (4).

I have a kubernetes_deployment resource that automatically deploys a fixed number of pods to the cluster. It was set to 20 when I had 2 nodes, and seemed evenly distributed with 10 each. I doubled that number to 40.

All of the new pods for the kubernetes deployment are being scheduled on the first 2 (original) nodes. Now the two original nodes have 20 pods each, while the 2 new nodes have 0 pods. The new nodes are up and ready to go, but I cannot get kubernetes to schedule the new pods on those new nodes.

I am unsure where to even begin searching, as I am fairly new to k8s and ops in general.

A few beginner questions that may be related:

1. I'm reading about pod affinity, and it seems like I could tell k8s to have a pod ANTI affinity with itself within a deployment. However, I am having trouble setting up the anti-affinity rules. I see that the [kubernetes_deployment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/deployment#preferred_during_scheduling_ignored_during_execution) resource has a scheduling argument, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.
2. Naively it seems that the issue may be that the deployment somehow isn't aware of the new nodes. If that is the case, how could I reboot the entire deployment (without taking down the already-running pods)?
3. Is there a cluster level scheduler that I need to set? I was under the impression that the default does round robin, which doesn't seem to be happening at the node level.

EDIT:
The EKS terraform module [node_groups submodule](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/11.0.0/submodules/node_groups) has fields for desired/min/max_capacity. To increase my worker nodes, I just increased those numbers. The change is reflected in the aws eks console.

Comment: If the two new worker nodes provisioned by Terraform are equivalent to the two existing worker nodes (i.e. the list was merely doubled and not modified afterwards within the config), then this is related to your configurations for the scheduler. If the scheduler is configured for bin-packing, then this behavior would also occur.

Comment: The EKS terraform module node_groups submodule (https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/11.0.0/submodules/node_groups) has fields for desired/min/max_capacity. To increase my worker nodes, I just increased those numbers. 

Where would I find the scheduler configurations? AFAIK I haven't set anything, so I assume it is using the default

Comment: If you modified the capacity arguments in `terraform-aws-eks`, then this behavior is indeed extrinsic to Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Check a couple of things:

1. Do your nodes show up correctly in the output of `kubectl get nodes -o wide` and do they have a state of ready?
2. Instead of pod affinity look into [pod topology spread constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/). Anti affinity will not work with multiple pods.